# Regretful "for" or "of"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Would it be correct to use "regretful" with "for" or "of"

> "I'm grateful for my present but regretful 'of' my past"

Is the "of" correct in context or it should be "for"

Answer (score 1):

I think "of" sounds more natural but "for" is not strictly incorrect before a gerund (-ing form) verb: "He was regretful of passing up the opportunity." "She was regretful of having caused a scene."

Before a noun, "of" would be the only correct choice: "They were regretful of the decision to unplug the server before checking that the backup had completed."

That said, I have almost never heard it used! I always hear regret used as a verb instead, as in "I am grateful for my present situation but regret a lot about my past."

Answer (score 0):

The adjective *regretful* (feeling regret for something done or undone) may be followed by prepositions *about, for, of and over*.

Here are the examples:

> If you decide to leave him, you'll be regretful *about* the decision
> for the rest of your life
>
> Be grateful for what you have, not regretful *for* what you haven't.
>
> He is regretful *of* his misdeeds.
>
> Some day, she will make him regretful *over* his unfair treatment.

Also, regretful is often followed by the conjunction *that*:

> He was really regretful that he had said those words.

The frequency of the usage with lots of other examples may be seen [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=regretful+for%2Cregretful+of%2Cregretful+with%2Cregretful+over%2Cregretful+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cregretful%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cregretful%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cregretful%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cregretful%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cregretful%20that%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score -1):

I think *of* is more correct.

> *Never afraid of what the future holds, never **regretful of** the present. That's who we are! The Dai-Gurren Brigade!* (Gurren Lagann, Episode 26, 2007)